# How do I randomly show k 'Q groups' from n Q groups in limesurvey

Tags: limesurvey

I have built a survey with 100 question groups of which I need to randomly show 10 question groups to each user, as it will be tedious for a single user to answer all 100 question groups, and I want to show a particular question group to all the users.

Now, I know I can create 10 surveys and then achieve the same, but I would like to show 10 random questions per user from the collection of 100. I also need to show one mandatory question group as well

Answer (score 2):

1. Add a equation question type Hidden at start of your survey, code GOON and question text to 1 (before the random's group)

   1. For you 100 question group : use same 'random group name', and set the relevance to 'GOON'.
   2. After the 10 group of this part : Add a group with an hidden equation question SETGOON with question text to {GOON=0} (and without a 'random group name')
   3. You can use this group for other question (mandatory too).

You need last 2.05 version to achieve this correctly.

Comment: Not a single post in lime survey's forums with any hint for how to achieve this. This is brilliant!